# How to convert a dataframe into an plot visual array matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix, plot

I have the data.frame with ten water quality parameters from 19 sub-basins from land use.

I would like to present these data in the form of a 19x10 graphical matrix. Vertically the sub-basin and horizontally the quality parameters.

I won't be able to send this data.frame here, but I put a similar example.

EDIT:

```
df<-read.table(text="parameter  basin   land
ph  1   3.02
COD 1   1.37
OD  1   1.25
N   1   1.85
ph  2   1,71
COD 2   2.02
OD  2   2.96
N   2   1.59
ph  3   2.42
COD 3   2.81
OD  3   1.56
N   3   1.43
", sep = "", header = TRUE)

View(df)
```

i tried `as.matrix` and `plot` but it didn't work

```
df2<-df%>%
  as.matrix()
plot(df2)
```

I edited the expectation, because I didn't express myself correctly. I use the transreader for a few things.

[image]

Comment: make sure to include `dec = ","` when you read the data ...

Comment: ... and a base R version `image(xtabs(land ~ basin + parameter, df))`

Comment: @user20650, post as answer please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Afer using `dec=","` as Ben suggets) first we can transform the data to a wide format and then use `image` to plot.

```
# The continuous variable is on the left-hand side of the formula
# You can control which categorical variable is on the x-axis 
# by changing the order of the variables in the right-hand side of 
# the formula, or else transpose the matrix with `t`
trans_df <- xtabs(land ~ basin + parameter, df)
image(trans_df)
```

---

Re your edit: you can add values to an image plot using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406508/r-axis-label-in-image/27407719#27407719). I use the `fields::imagePlot` function as it is an easy way to add the colourbar.

```
trans_df <- xtabs(land ~ basin + parameter, df)
#     parameter
# basin  COD    N   OD   ph
#     1 1.37 1.85 1.25 3.02
#     2 2.02 1.59 2.96 1.71
#     3 2.81 1.43 1.56 2.42
    
library(fields) # for the easy heatmap

# Transpose matrix so that it plots in the same order as 
# it looks in the table above
imagePlot( t(trans_df[nrow(trans_df):1, ]), axes=FALSE)

# add values in cells
e <- expand.grid(seq(0,1, length=ncol(trans_df)), seq(1,0, length=nrow(trans_df)))
text(e, labels=t(trans_df), cex=2, col="black")

# axis labels
axis(3, at=seq(0,1, length=ncol(trans_df)), labels=colnames(trans_df), cex=2)
axis(2, at=seq(1,0, length=nrow(trans_df)), labels=rownames(trans_df), cex=2)
```

[image]

---

Actually it may be easier just to use `corrplot`:

```
library(corrplot)
corrplot(trans_df, is.corr = FALSE, method = "color",  addCoef.col = 'black')
```

[image]

Comment: hello, I edited my question in anticipation

Comment: @wesleysc352; please see update

Comment: Fantastic. I managed to replicate the solution here. `xtabs` is an interesting solution. `corrplot` is even better!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

A way with `ggplot2`

```
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = basin,y = parameter,fill = land))+
  geom_tile(col = "white")+
  scale_fill_viridis_b()+
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0))+
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Helo, your answer is interesting, but in the answer the `basin` variable is like a numeric variable, but it is a `factor`